# memcache heartbeat property not working

Tags: java, linux, memcached

I am using xemcached 1.3.8 with repcached replication on it .

Inside my code i have set `setEnableHeartBeat(false);` to false and also i am passing , environment variable through script `-Dxmemcached.heartbeat.max.fail.times=2`

But still in case if one server is down in cluster , it is continuously trying to connect to that server .

please let me know how can i make this try to reconnect only for 2 times .

As you saw i tried setting from code as well as from environemnt variable but still its continously trying to ping the down server

And moreover i also added environemnt varaible this way

System.setProperty("xmemcached.heartbeat.max.fail.times", "2");

But i dont know why it keeps on trying to the down server .